# Why does Ghost script 10.02.01 rotate barcode elements 180 degrees counterclockwise?

Tags: windows, pdf, rotation, ghostscript, postscript

When converting a postscript file to PDF using the following command line, the barcode elements are flipped 180 degrees counter clockwise, above the correct origin and overlaying text. The rest of the elements are correct.
Adobe Distiller converts it correctly.

C:\tmp\gs_test>"C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.02.1\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dQUIET -o"DC2008y2_gs.pdf" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r812 -IFONTDIR="\asgard\production\Label System\Fonts;C:\Windows\fonts" -f "DC2008_001.ps" -c quit

[Correct image from Adobe Distiller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM6XQ.png)

[Incorrect image from gswin64c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dy8B.png)

If I add -c "<</Orientation 2>> setpagedevice" to the command line, it seems to rotate the labels from the bottom left origin, making it the new top right. This causes all of them to be shifted left.
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.02.1\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dQUIET -o"sample2_gs.pdf" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r812 -c "<</Orientation 2>> setpagedevice" -f "sample.ps" -c quit

[Rotated 180](https://i.stack.imgur.com/celsz.png)

Comment: Probably because it's set as text and you've left AutoRotatePages set to the default, but as K J says, can't possibly tell without seeing an example file. The pictures aren't of sufficient quality, and its almost always impossible to tell what's going on without an example file as well as a command line. Why on earth are you setting the resolution to 812 dpi ? That doesn't make any sense since PDF is basically resolution-independent.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @KJ.  I trimmed down the original files as much as I could, due to my limited experience with postscript. The file was too large to put here so I added it to pastebin, named "Crackers Sample Postscript" https://pastebin.com/0aNDeZCh  If you run that through the distiller it works fine, through ghostscript it re-creates the issue. Command Line: "C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.02.1\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dQUIET -o"sample2_gs.pdf" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r812 -f "sample.ps" -c quit

Comment: @KenS - Please see previous comment and edit to post.

Comment: If changing the Orientation makes a difference then that will be due to the content of the original PostScript program. I'm not going to speculate any further though, I'd need to see the original PostScript, not pictures of the output.

Comment: The short answer, as far as I can see, is that Acrobat is flipping the page vertically. If I dump the CTM at the beginning of the file (**before** the %!) then it is given by Acrobat as [8.33333 0.0 0.0 -8.33333 -2550.0 3300.5]. That's a vertical flip and a scale by 8.3 (because the default resolution is 600 dpi). Ghostscript by contrast has a CTM of [10 0 0 10 0 0] Which is a simple scale by 10 (because the default resolution for pdfwrite is 720 dpi). I've no idea how Distiller manages to get sensible output like that. The file is too complex to investigate if you simplify it I'll look again.

Comment: @KenS. I was able to shrink the .ps input file from 5400 to under 350 lines. I hope this helps. I removed everything but the barcodes and the text above the codes. I included the input file and the output files from both Adobe and Ghostscript. I also included some additional files, the output with removing the -r812 parm and the Adobe distiller options file, if that helps. The files are in filetransfer.io as suggested by @K J. Let me know if there's anything else that may help. Thanks!

https://filetransfer.io/data-package/5FowNF9K#link

Comment: It looks to me like the problem is that this particular PostScript program is non-portable. It will only work properly at a specific resolution. This is because of the 'mt' function (and others) which is transforming co-ordinates back and forth between user space and device space. I believe this will give different results based on the current resolution (because the CTM depends on the resolution). To get the results you expect/want you will have to know what the correct resolution is and tell Ghostscript to use it. Even that may not be sufficient.

Comment: Hi @KenS. The correct resolution is 812 dpi, which is a requirement of the presses these files drive. However, as you know that still causes a problem. So, are you thinking ghostscript will not be able to convert these files? Any idea how the distiller gets it right? Is there a way to get ghostscript to use the distiller joboptions file?

Comment: No, you can't get Ghostscript to use the Distiller jonoptions file (nor would it make any difference). Beyond the fact that the job is resolution dependent I have no idea how Distiller gets this correct except to note that Distiller flips the CTM vertically. If the file is intended for use on an interpreter where this is the case that would explain it. It's by no means obvious to me how Distiller gets the correct output for other files with a CTM like this. I'd have to investigate much further to figure this out because the file is still way too complex.

Comment: @KenS. I Pulled out more from the postscript to try to simplify it and resolved everything I could down to its value, but it's probably not enough. I tried to make sense of what mt, LBR and LSPC are doing but couldn't. I believe this is what you were referring to when you say the code is too complex and it does a lot of switching from user to device space. I've added a new set of files. If there's any information you can provide that you think may help, like how to dump the CTM or additional resources or advice I would appreciate it. Thanks!
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/IFr5ZTaS#link

Comment: What I really meant is there are too many elements in the file, the functions are fairly straightforward, but the use of transform and itransform make the program device-dependent. Once you have a device-dependent program, running it on another device may give unexpected, or incorrect, answers. I'll try and find time to look at it but I'm extremely busy right at the moment.

Comment: You can print the CTM with "matrix currentmatrix == flush" any object can be printed in PostScript but composite objects (usually just dictionaries with Ghostscript) need to be iterated over eg "{== == flush} forall"

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this @KenS. This may not help but here are the CTM dumps on my system before %!, after the /PageSize command and after the EOF. I appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks again!

[-10.0 0.0 0.0 -10.0 6120.0 7920.0] - Before %!
[-10.0 0.0 0.0 -10.0 8208.0 27360.0] - After PageSize
[-10.0 0.0 0.0 -10.0 8208.0 27360.0] - EOF

Comment: So, as I said, it's because Distiller has an inverting CTM initially ([11.2778 0.0 0.0 -11.2778 -3451.0 4466.5]) whereas Ghostscript has a standard CTM ([11.2777777 0.0 0.0 11.2777777 0.0 0.0]). Because the program uses transform and itransform to update the co-ordinates in device space and then transform them back to user space (which makes it a devoice-dependent program) the movement and direction in Distiller is 180 degrees to the movement with Ghostscript. Neither is incorrect, you should not use transform and itransform in portable programs.

Comment: I was able to get the correct results by flipping the following variables to negative. It changes the direction of drawing the barcode from going up to going down. 
1. /b1 15 def
2. /b2 31 def
3. /b3 47 def
4. /b4 63 def
5. /s1 17 def
6. /s2 33 def
7. /s3 49 def
8. /s4 65 def

to:
9. /b1 -15 def
10. /b2 -31 def
11. /b3 -47 def
12. /b4 -63 def
13. /s1 -17 def
14. /s2 -33 def
15. /s3 -49 def
16. /s4 -65 def

Comment: The movement is calculated in device space, while the object drawing commands are in user space. That is, pretty much, a recipe for things to go wrong. As I said, the problem is that the PostScript program uses transform/itransform to fiddle in device space, which makes it non-portable. I've tried two other PostScript interpreters and they behave the same as Ghostscript. Which makes me believe the program was developed against Adobe Distiller and won't work as expected on any other device.